# Unexpected confidence interval using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, confidence-interval, scipy.stats

I calculated a 95% confidence interval using scipy and the result is different to what I was expecting.

I am solving a problem where someone rolled a die 20K times and observed 3,932 sixes. I am being asked to build a 95% confidence interval for the probability of rolling a six. The number of sixes follows a binomial distribution with 20K repetitions and a probability of success of 3,932  / 20K.

```py
# Number of observations
n_obs = 20000

# Observed proportion of successes
p_obs = 3932 / n_obs

# Observed standard deviation
s_obs = numpy.sqrt((p_obs * (1 - p_obs)) / n_obs)
```

If I use a normal approximation with these parameters, the confidence interval should be `p_obs` ± 1.96 * `s_obs`. That is, between 0.1911 and 0.2021.

However, if I do the following, it returns a completely different interval.

```py
# Declare normal random variable
X = scipy.stats.norm(loc=p_obs, scale=s_obs)

# Get interval
X.interval(alpha=0.05)
> (0.1964, 0.1968)        # Different to what I was expecting
```

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really counter-intuitive, but it turns out that the `alpha` parameter in the `interval()` method is the probability of the distribution contained within the edges of the interval.

Hence, the correct way of calculating the 95% confidence interval is:

```py
X.interval(alpha=0.95)
> (0.19109204017782955, 0.20210795982217045)
```

This goes against the standard nomenclature used in statistics, so I raised an [issue on](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13835) GitHub. Apparently it also causes name collisions with other methods.